# a Haskell program using Head and Tail to relate 2 strings

Tags: haskell

I need to determine whether a string is a substring of another string.
I think is comparing the head of one string with the head and the other string,afterwards with the head of the tail and so on .But then I need to compare each element of the supossed substring with the other string,Then I think is needed take help of the function map.But i dont know how to write the program.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Data.List.isInfixOf](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-List.html#g:12):

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)
import System (getArgs)

main = do [needle, haystack] <- getArgs
          if needle `isInfixOf` haystack
            then putStrLn $ concat [show needle, " is in ", show haystack]
            else putStrLn $ concat [show needle, " is NOT in ", show haystack]
```

---

"Substring" does not mean what you think it means. Hence, confusion. Does this do what you want?

```
import Data.List (all)

someFunction :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
someFunction needle haystack = all (`elem` haystack) needle

main = do [needle, haystack] <- getArgs
          if needle `someFunction` haystack
            then putStrLn $ concat [show needle, " is in ", show haystack]
            else putStrLn $ concat [show needle, " is NOT in ", show haystack]
```

I am still not sure whether this is what you want.

Do you want `` "cc" `someFunction` "abcde" `` to return True (because `'c'` is in `"abcde"`) or False (because `'c'` is only in `"abcde"` once)?

Do you want `` "db" `someFunction` "abcde" `` to return (because `'d'` and `'b'` are both in `"abcde"`) or False (because they do not appear in that order)?

Comment: @julia What do you mean to say?

Comment: interesting ,but i understand that this function isInfixOf would be useful only in the case that the elements of the substring follow the sequence of the elements of the string.for example if myString=[a,b,c,d,e,] and mysubString=[b,d], the substring is not sufix ,is not prefix,it also is not in the middle as a whole ,but the elements of the sub sting are in the string.Then How to do? for that I was trying to use isEqual, head and tail and map testing each element of the string but i could not do it.

Comment: Either I misunderstand what you want, or you misunderstand what `isInfixOf` does. ``"bcd" `isInfixOf` "abcde"`` is True; ``"bd" `isInfixOf` "abcde"`` is False. I thought that was what you wanted. Is that what you want? If you want ``"bd" `someFunction` "abcde"`` to return True, then what do you want ``"db" `someFunction` "abcde"`` to return? What do you want ``"cc" `someFunction` "abcde"`` to return?

Comment: when "bd" `isInfixOf` "abcde" is False means bd is not a substring of the string abcde,(because the function `isInfixOf`test the substring as a whole and c is in between), but bd is substring of abdce,because the elements of the substring are in the string.I need ckeck if the elements of one string (substring)are in the other string

Comment: @julia: Usually, the term "substring" refers to a contiguous subsequence, which doesn't seem to be what you're after. Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify the exact behavior you want to implement?

Comment: @julia: See my edit. "Substring" does not mean what you think it means. I'm still not sure what you want.

Comment: @dave4420 yes,you are right,my concept of substring was wrong.Then your two edits are useful.Because now really i need to do 2 tasks,one is to know if one string is substring of other( now i know what exactly substring is)and the other is to know if all the characters of one string are in the other string.

Comment: @cancaccann:now i understood the concept substring ,in the previous comment tell what i want to do ,is you know other implementation appling head and Tail will be useful too

Comment: @dave4420: I think _julia_ wants to check if the set consisting of the letters of one sting is a subset of the set consisting of the letters of another string. See **Edit 3** in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292613/a-haskell-program-using-head-and-tail-to-relate-2-strings/6293501#6293501)

Comment: @MarcoS. Icannot to load the modules. Program tell "parse error on the input 'import'.I wrote 'import data.list'.What will be the problem?

Comment: @julia: it is case sensitive: it should be `import Data.List`. Please note that the last solution that I wrote actually uses `Data.Set`. See **Edit 3** in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292613/a-haskell-program-using-head-and-tail-to-relate-2-strings/6293501#6293501)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll be interested in the `(\\)` function available in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a `subString` function, then here's my attempt:

```
subString :: String -> String -> Bool
subString xs [] = True
subString [] _ = False
subString (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = ys == take (length ys) xs
  | otherwise = subString xs (y:ys)
```

Examples:

```
*Main> subString "MarcoS" "arc"
True
*Main> subString "MarcoS" "marc"
False
*Main> subString "MarcoS" ""
True
*Main> subString "" "a"
False
```

I realize this is not using `head` and `tail`, but that's how I would do it.

---

**Edit**

After looking at the [source code for `isInfixOf`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/src/Data-List.html#isInfixOf) (as suggested by [dave4420](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292613/a-haskell-program-using-head-and-tail-to-relate-2-strings/6292983#6292983), I realize there's a neat way and more general way of doing this using `tails` ... one never stops learning :)

---

**Edit 2**

From the comments I understand that the question actually ask to check if a string contains all the letters of another string in any order, or more generally if a list of elements contains all the elements of another list in any order. So, here's my implementation:

```
import Data.List

-- does xs containsAll ys? containsAll xs ys
containsAll :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
containsAll _ [] = True
containsAll [] _ = False
containsAll xs ys = elem ys $ concatMap (permutations) (subsequences xs)
```

Examples:

```
*Main> containsAll "pippo" "pppp"
False
*Main> containsAll "pippo" "ppp"
True
*Main> containsAll "pippo" "ppi"
True
*Main> containsAll "pippo" "ipp"
True
```

Probably there are other (better) ways, which I'm curious to learn about :)

---

**Edit 3**

From yet other comments I understand that the problem is essentially subset checking, that is checking if all the letters of a string are also in another string. So, here is one way of doing it:

```
-- are all xs in ys? allin xs ys
allIn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
allIn xs ys = and $ map (flip elem ys) xs
```

Alternatively, one can use [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html) to wite:

```
import Data.Set

allIn :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
allIn xs ys = (fromList xs) `isSubsetOf` (fromList ys)
```

Examples:

```
*Main Data.Set> "ppp" `allIn` "pippo"
True
*Main Data.Set> "ipp" `allIn` "pippo"
True
*Main Data.Set> "pppp" `allIn` "pippo"
True
```

Comment: `subString "" "a"` should be `True`.

Comment: @MarcoS - thanks for posting that source link, it certainly is a clever use of `tails`, but how is it 'more general' than any other use?  Do you just mean `tail` vs `tails`?

Comment: but how to do if the elements of the substring are not in the same sequence of the string? supose MarcoS and car

Comment: @julia: I've edited my answer to address your comment: see **Edit 2**

Comment: @jon_darkstar: I meant "more general than my implementation" :)

Comment: @MarcoS-Yes you understood what I want to check if all the elements of one string are in another string in any order BUT also in any quantity/repetition.Then your implementation in this manner would not be useful for me because according your function  "pippo" "pppp" is false but the element p of the string "pppp" is in the string "pippo"

Comment: @MarcoS-I am tring to use your first edit to test if one string if substring of another because looks very easy form,but is it possible to explain me how work take(lenght ys)...?

Comment: @julia: I see from your comment that you want subset-checking: I've edited my answer to address this: see **Edit 3**

Comment: @julia: `take (length ys) xs` returns the first n characters of `xs` where n is equal to `length ys`. Anyway, have a look at my edited answer (Edit 3)